# iOS Horizontal Scrolling Calendar

Tags: objective-c, ios, horizontalscrollview

Some background. I'm helping a group of students at my son's school and they want to write a simple tracking app that managers student observations that will be used on iPod Touch.

I've only done very basic iOS development using the standard widgets, but I'm keen to help.

We worked through and designed the functionality and interface of the app and are now starting to program. Where I am out of my depth is that they want to have a strip running along the bottom of the screen with each day as a little block displaying the date and date and an indicator to show if there was an observation for that day.

I was hoping that you guys might be able to point me in the right direction, either an existing widget or explain in detail how to achieve this. I've tried a few approaches with no luck.

I'd appreciate any assistance with this as I know this must be a common requirement, but I'm struggling to get through this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thought I'd post my final solution in case others find it useful.

In view root view controller I added a custom UITableViewController which basically rotates the table 90 degrees and then rotates each table cell -90 degrees. It does what I want is was pretty straight forward.

Code for root view controller. This sets the size and position of the table :

```
scrollingDateViewController=[[ScrollingDateViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScrollingDateView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
CGRect rect=CGRectMake(0,330,320,100);    
scrollingDateViewController.view.frame=rect;
scrollingDateViewController.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
scrollingDateViewController.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:scrollingDateViewController.view];
```

Key Code for ScrollingDateViewController. This rotates the table 90 degrees and the each cell -90 degress :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
today = [[NSDate alloc] init];    
CGRect rect=self.view.frame;
myTableView.frame=rect;
myTableView.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DIdentity,1.57079633,0,0,1);
myTableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
myTableView.separatorColor=[UIColor clearColor];
myTableView.frame=rect;
myTableView.rowHeight=44;  // cellWidth
myTableView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=NO;
myTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=NO;
myTableView.separatorColor=nil;
```

}

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tableCell"];
if(!cell){
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"tableCell"];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_back.png"]];
    cell.contentView.transform =  CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-1.57079633);
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

    // Add background image view
    CGRect rect=CGRectZero;
    UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    imgView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    imgView.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DIdentity,-1.57079633,0,0,1);
    imgView.tag=101;
    [cell addSubview:imgView];

    rect.origin.x=0;
    rect.origin.y=0;
    rect.size.height=80;
    rect.size.width=44;
    imgView.frame=rect;
    [imgView release];

    // Add Day Label
    UILabel *dayLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    dayLabel.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DIdentity,-1.57079633,0,0,1);
    dayLabel.tag=102;
    dayLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Geogrotesque-Medium" size:14.0];
    dayLabel.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
    dayLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    dayLabel.textColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];

    [cell addSubview:dayLabel];
    rect.origin.x=40;
    rect.origin.y=0;
    rect.size.height=44;
    rect.size.width=20;
    dayLabel.frame=rect;
    [dayLabel release];

    // Add Date Label
    UILabel *dateLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    dateLabel.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DIdentity,-1.57079633,0,0,1);
    dateLabel.tag=103;
    dateLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Geogrotesque-Bold" size:18.0 ];
    dateLabel.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
    dateLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    dateLabel.textColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];

    [cell addSubview:dateLabel];
    rect.origin.x=55;
    rect.origin.y=0;
    rect.size.height=44;
    rect.size.width=20;
    dateLabel.frame=rect;

    [dateLabel release];
}

UILabel *label=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:102];
label.text= [self getDayString:displayDate];
label=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:103];
label.text= [self getDateString:displayDate];
return cell;

}
```

Comment: Hi Zoran, I working on a similar component and your solution seems to be relevant to where I am a little stuck at the moment. 

I wonder if you had to implement an infinite scrolling as part of this project?

Comment: I used a really large number for the table size and then just dynamically calculate the date for each cell. I couldn't see any other way around it.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you should create a view which you want to be shown for each date. Create something like

```
@interface DayView : UIView {
```

You can implement it with nib or make everything programmatically in drawRect method.

After it go to your Xcode documentation and search for UIScrollView. Xcode will provide your with code samples, use project "Scrolling" to find out how to use scrollView. In this sample they scroll pics, and you replace them with our custom DayViews.

Good luck!

Comment: The reason I opted for the UITableView approach is that to get the lazy loading functionality I need, I can just use UITableView dequeing features where as with UIScrollView, I'd have to implement the same behaviour myself. The fact is, that with my limited experience, I used the first technique which worked.